# Iterate over names to create new columns and get data with same names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, printf, apply

I'm having some issues trying to do what I think is quite simple.

I have a list of names:

```
the_names <- c("X1", "X2")
```

I want to use these names as column names in a new data frame *and* use these names to pull data from another data frame.

This list of names is going to be of varying length depending on the sample. So, it will not always be of length 2 (X1, X2).

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
pair_meta <- data.frame()
  
  for(i in the_names) {
    # create a column using the name from the list
    # reference name to get data from other data frames (bed_A)
    pair_meta[[i]] <- bed_A[i]
  }
```

Where the iterator, i, is X1 then X2 (then X3 etc. if the list of names is longer).

I am having trouble getting the column names of the data frame to match the list of input names, and I am having trouble using the same name to gather data from another file.

For more context, here is the bit of code I am working on:

```
       pair <- data.frame(
              chr1   = rep( bed_A[anchor,"chr"  ] , length(tail_entry:head_entry) ),
              start1 = rep( bed_A[anchor,"start"] , length(tail_entry:head_entry) ),
              end1   = rep( bed_A[anchor,"end"  ] , length(tail_entry:head_entry) ),
              
              chr2   = bed_B[tail_entry:head_entry,"chr"  ],
              start2 = bed_B[tail_entry:head_entry,"start"],
              end2   = bed_B[tail_entry:head_entry,"end"  ]
            )
```

In this "pair" data frame, there are 6 columns with hard-coded names (chr1, start1, end1, chr2, start2, end 2). In this table, there will always be 6 columns with these names.

I am trying to create an additional table that stores metadata associated with this data. There may be any number of metadata columns. I have already collected a list of the metadata columns and named them X1 through Xn and stored them as "the_names".

So, what I am wondering, is how to create a table of metadata that matches the pair data. I want to do this:

```
for(i in the_names) {

pair_meta[[i]] <- rep( bed_A[anchor, i],length(tail_entry:head_entry))

}
```

So that the resulting pair_meta dataframe would have i number of columns, named using the list of names, and reference some other data in another data frame.

For example, how can I do this:

```
 chr1   = rep( bed_A[anchor,"chr"  ] , length(tail_entry:head_entry) )
```

without a hard-coded variable name, and instead with a flexible placeholder?

```
X1   = rep( bed_A[anchor,"X1"  ] , length(tail_entry:head_entry) )
and
X2   = rep( bed_A[anchor,"X2"  ] , length(tail_entry:head_entry) )
etc.
```

Is there a way to do this with a loop and an iterator? something like:

```
i   = rep( bed_A[anchor,"i"  ] , length(tail_entry:head_entry) )
etc.
```

I hope these edits clarify my issue here. I wanted to include a reproducible example so I made some simple data, but I think that confused everyone trying to help.

I've tried everything I've posted here, sprintf, and apply functions. Please help!

Comment: How comes your desired output is same as the input?

Comment: @onyambu because it's just a simple example focused on the method

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I hope this helps

```
the_names <- c("X1", "X2") # issue 1: string items in vector must be wrapped individually in ""
bed_A <- data.frame(X1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), X2 = rep("E", 5))
n_row <- nrow(bed_A)
pair_meta <- data.frame( # issue 2: row length mismatch, add column with number of rows matching bed_A
    id <- 1:n_row
)
for (i in the_names) {
    pair_meta <- cbind(pair_meta, bed_A[i]) # correct way to add a column to a dataframe   
}
print(pair_meta)

# you could also combine the dataframe like this and avoid making an unnecessary column
pair_meta <- data.frame( # add column with number of rows matching bed_A
    id <- 1:n_row
)
pair_meta <- cbind(bed_A)
print(pair_meta)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think I did a poor job of explaining what I'm after. I am trying to figure out how to iterate over a list of names (which can be of variable length) and use those names as column names. I'm going to try to clarify my question.